# Angular js : Dynamic expression not working for ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I have a div based on switch but the switch has a boolean variable(hasUrl)  and expression. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
  <div ng-switch="hasUrl && row.id.indexOf(':') < 0">
    <a ng-switch-when="true" href="{{url + row.id}}"> 
    {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default href=".......">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: It seems to me you'd be better off using `ng-attr-href="url&row.id.indexOf(':')<0?url+row.id:'......'"`

Comment: This is from the documentation, for ngSwitch: `Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against.`